# Как перегрузить оператор [] для доступа к элементам vector-а?

Tags: c++, vector

У меня есть `vector`, который содержит объекты структуры.
Как можно осуществить доступ к элементам структуры через `vector`?

```
struct ex {
    string hello;
}


vector<ex> Vec;
ex o1, o2, o3;
Vec.push_back(o1);
Vec.push_back(o2);
Vec.push_back(o3);
for (int i = 0; i < Vec.size(); i ++) {
    Vec[i].hello;
}
```

Comment: поставьте тег конктретного языка ([tag:С++] ?)

Comment: А проблема-то в чем?..

Comment: Не могу получить доступ к элементам структуры, с помощью итерации

Comment: @Mr.Hello_world: А что вы называете словосочетанием «получить доступ»?

Comment: @VladD Vec[1].hello; но с помощью итерации , чтобы можно было изменять значения элементов структуры

Comment: хотите обращаться к Vec[1].hello[1] как `Vec[1][1]` ?

Comment: @Mr.Hello_world: Не понимаю, а чем ваш текущий код не подходит? Ну напишите `Vec[i].hello = "123";` внутри цикла.

Comment: @sercxjo, да!!!)

Comment: @Mr. Hello_world, для этого вам просто нужно перегрузить `operator[]` для структуры `ex`. `char& operator[](ex& obj, size_t index) { return obj.hello[index]; }` и  `const char& operator[](const ex& obj, size_t index) { return obj.hello[index]; }`

Answer (score 2):

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая показывает некоторые методы работы с вектором структур, когда структура является агрегатом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Greeting 
{
    std::string hello;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Greeting> v = { { "Hello" }, { "Mr." }, { "Hello_world" } };        

    for ( const Greeting &g : v ) std::cout << g.hello << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    v[0] = { "Bye" };

    for ( const Greeting &g : v ) std::cout << g.hello << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    v.insert( v.end(), { { "See" }, { "you" }, { "soon" } } );

    for ( const Greeting &g : v ) std::cout << g.hello << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    v[0].hello = "Ciao";

    for ( const Greeting &g : v ) std::cout << g.hello << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
Hello Mr. Hello_world 
Bye Mr. Hello_world 
Bye Mr. Hello_world See you soon 
Ciao Mr. Hello_world See you soon
```

Перегружать оператор `operator []` имело бы смысл, если бы у вас был не вектор структур, а структура, содержащая вектор. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Greeting 
{
    std::vector<std::string> hello;

    std::string & operator []( size_t i )
    {
        return hello[i];
    }        

    const std::string & operator []( size_t i ) const
    {
        return hello[i];
    }

    size_t size() const { return hello.size(); }
};

int main()
{
    Greeting g = { { { "Hello" }, { "Mr." }, { "Hello_world" } } };        

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < g.size(); i++ ) std::cout << g[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    g[0] = "Bye";

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < g.size(); i++ ) std::cout << g[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    g.hello.insert( g.hello.end(), { { "See" }, { "you" }, { "soon" } } );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < g.size(); i++ ) std::cout << g[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    g.hello[0] = "Ciao";

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < g.size(); i++ ) std::cout << g[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет точно таким, как было показано выше:

```
Hello Mr. Hello_world 
Bye Mr. Hello_world 
Bye Mr. Hello_world See you soon 
Ciao Mr. Hello_world See you soon
```